# How to apply CSS directives to h3 element?

Tags: css

To see what I mean, take a look at [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g0cutgc5/).  (Note: that the "Normalized CSS" option is set for this jsFiddle.)

Bottom line: same CSS directives applied to `span` and `h3` elements produce very different results (different vertical alignments and background colors).

I want the vertical alignment and background color of the `h3.letter` element to be as shown for the `span.letter` element.

---

*Is there a way to force the application of these directives to the `h3` element?*

---

(Also, I'd be grateful if someone would point me to some specific bit of information [e.g. a specific paragraph in W3C's documentation maze] that would make the behavior described here easier to understand.)

---

BTW, the code is a slight adaptation of the recipe given [here](http://blogs.adobe.com/webplatform/2014/08/13/one-weird-trick-to-baseline-align-text/).

---

Here's the code, to appease SE:

```
<div>
  <span class="letter">T</span>
  <span class="strut"></span>
</div>
<div>
  <h3 class="letter">T</h3>
  <span class="strut"></span>
</div>
```

```
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: thin black solid;
  margin: 50px;
}
.letter {
  font-size: 100px;
  line-height: 0px;
  background-color: #9BBCE3;
}
.strut {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues. One with `line-height: 0` that you have set and made `h3` `block` element zero heighted (so background doesn't shown) and second issue that default `display` value for each element is different so behavior is not the same.

Example 1 (without line-height):

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: thin black solid;
  margin: 100px;
}
.letter {
  font-size: 100px;
  /* line-height: 0px; */
  background-color: #9BBCE3;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.strut {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div> <span class="letter">T</span>
  <span class="strut"></span>
</div>
<div>
  <h3 class="letter">T</h3>
  <span class="strut"></span>
</div>
```

Example 2 (displayed both as inline):

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: thin black solid;
  margin: 100px;
}
.letter {
  font-size: 100px;
  /* line-height: 0px; */
  background-color: #9BBCE3;
  font-weight: 400;
  display: inline;
}
.strut {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div> <span class="letter">T</span>
  <span class="strut"></span>
</div>
<div>
  <h3 class="letter">T</h3>
  <span class="strut"></span>
</div>
```

Here are some references that may help you understand the difference between `inline` and `block` elements.

> **Inline**
>
> The default value for elements. Think of elements like `<span>`, `<em>`,
>   or `<b>` and how wrapping text in those elements within a string of text
>   doesn't break the flow of the text. An inline element will accept
>   margin and padding, but the element still sits inline as you might
>   expect. Margin and padding will only push other elements horizontally
>   away, not vertically. An inline element will not accept height and
>   width. It will just ignore it.
>
> **Block**
>
> A number of elements are set to block by the browser UA stylesheet.
>   They are usually container elements, like `<div>`, `<section>`, and `<ul>`.
>   Also text "blocks" like `<p>` and `<h1>`. Block level elements do not sit
>   inline but break past them. By default (without setting a width) they
>   take up as much horizontal space as they can.

CSS-Tricks: [display](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/)

MDN: [Inline elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elemente) - [Block-level elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements)

w3.org: [Inline-level elements and inline boxes](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#inline-boxes) - [Block-level elements and block boxes](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-boxes)

Answer (score 1):

Quick answer is that spans are `display:inline` while h3s are `display:block`.   Adding a rule `h3{display:inline;}` will make your h3 look like the span.

Still looking for a good example online to explain this.  Some CSS rules apply differently based on the display; for example, only block elements can use `width` rules.

MDN is pretty heavy, but has all the links to the spec:
[MDN display spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)

Answer (score 1):

Heading tags default to

```
display:block;
```

Span tags default to

```
display:inline;
```